# How to change colour scroll-overflow indicators?

Tags: dart, material-design, flutter

When the user scrolls to the edge of a list or TabView, an animated blue circle appears on the ending edge.

What is this called, and how do I change the colour of it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the android scroll physics ([ClampingScrollPhysics](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ClampingScrollPhysics-class.html)).

From the [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/e768c92fbc6cf8bf4e1814ef950a6092bbb6f658/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_physics.dart#L410) and docs:

> glow color is specified to use [ThemeData.accentColor].

That been said, when you create your `App`, the best practice is to specify a custom theme, istead of appling colors manually.

Example:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,

        primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
        primaryColor: Colors.grey[50],
        primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.light,

        //this is what you want
        accentColor: Colors.orangeAccent[400],
        accentColorBrightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}
```

I like to use [this tool](https://material.io/color/#!/) to define the primary and secondary (called accent color in flutter) and having a preview of the widgets.

Note: On IOs the physics is different, letting the user scroll beyond the bounds of the content, but then bounce the content back to the edge of those bounds ([BouncingScrollPhysics](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/BouncingScrollPhysics-class.html)).

Comment: Ah, perfect! Is there a way to disable this / make it transparent for a specific screen? My scrollable area is not full-screen, so the glowing area is cutoff vertically, and it looks a bit weird.

Comment: Perhaps using a different scroll physics, like the default: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ScrollPhysics-class.html
Just add the physics property to you ScrollView: `physics: ScrollPhysics()`

Answer (score 3):

Since Flutter v2.3.0-0.1.pre, themes changed
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/accentColor.html

For setting the accent color, you must do something like

```dart
class Themes {
  static final light = ThemeData(
      // Colors
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      primaryColor: MyColors.blue,
      splashColor: MyColors.blue,
      cardColor: MyColors.blue,
      hoverColor: MyColors.blue,
      highlightColor: MyColors.blue,
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: MyColors.blue),

      // Fonts
      fontFamily: 'Inter');

  static final lightV2 = light.copyWith(
      colorScheme: light.colorScheme.copyWith(secondary: MyColors.blue));
}
```

And assign `ligthV2` in your MaterialApp

```dart
MaterialApp(
   ...
   theme: Themes.lightV2
   ...
)
```